# SQL Server - Creating a trigger to send email after updating a column

Tags: triggers, sql-server-express

I'm creating a database for a rentals system for musical instruments where I want an email sent to the administrator when the residual value of an instrument is zero or less than zero. An earlier stored procedure updates this tables column `instrument_residual_value` when a payment is recorded in the `Payments` table.

The code I have is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER notify_balance
ON instrument
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NEW.instrument_residual_value <= 0 
        EXEC .msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
              @profile_name = 'manager',
              @recipients = 'manager_email@example.com',
              @subject = 'This instrument is paid off',
              @body = CONCAT('The residual value on ', [NEW.instrument_name], 'is now zero.');
END;
```

I'm getting a syntax error ostensibly in the `@body = CONCAT` line but I suspect that the keyword NEW is the issue as removing `NEW.instrument_name` from that line shifts the error to

```
IF NEW.instrument_residual_value <= 0
```

Is my code OK here or is there a better way of doing this?

Using SQL Server 2022 Express.

After reading  marc_s' comment my code now reads

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.notify_balance_zero   
   ON  dbo.instrument 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 

BEGIN        
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @instrument VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT INSERTED.instrument_name 
                                         FROM INSERTED 
                                         WHERE INSERTED.instrument_residual_value <= 0 )
                                         
    IF @instrument IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            EXEC .msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                @profile_name = 'manager',
                @recipients = 'manager_email@example.com',
                @subject = 'This instrument is paid off',
                @body = CONCAT('The residual value on ', [INSERTED.instrument_name], 'is now zero.');
        END

END
GO
```

Is this valid ads I still get an error in the @body line?

Comment: T-SQL triggers use `Inserted` and `Deleted` as aliases for the pseudo tables that contain the new and old data rows - not `NEW.` ..... mind you that these pseudo tables can and will contain **multiple rows** - so you need to use them in a proper, set-based fashion to avoid common trigger errors

Comment: If I understand this correctly the 'deleted' table holds the information in the row before an update or delete instruction and the 'inserted' table holds the row after  an update or insert instruction, so I should search the INSERTED table and if the RV field is zero execute the send mail.

Comment: As I already said - `Inserted` is basically a **table** of multiple rows - you cannot just reference it like this: `[INSERTED.instrument_name]` when building your `@body` ! And the line fetching the `@instrument` also doesn't take into account that there might be multiple rows in `Inserted` ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that neither the CONCAT nor COALESCE statement is acceptable if you're creating a trigger. The following code at least ran and created the trigger.

```
   CREATE TRIGGER notify_balance_zero 
   ON  instrument 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @instrument_name VARCHAR(MAX) = (
        SELECT INSERTED.instrument_name  
        FROM INSERTED 
        WHERE INSERTED.instrument_residual_value <= 0 )
        EXEC .msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @recipients = 'manager_email@example.com'
            ,@subject = @instrument_name
            ,@body = 'The balance on this instrument is now Zero, (or less)'
;
END
GO
```

Don't know if it works for real yet though.